# What parameters does to_json take in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  def show
    email = UserEmail.find_by_key(UserEmail.key_for(UserEmail.new(:publisher_id => @publisher.name, :app_id => @app ? @app.name : 'none', :external_uid => @user.external_uid)))
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render :xml => @user.to_xml(:session => false, :authorized => user_logged_in? || publisher_logged_in? || app_logged_in?, :publisher => @publisher, :email => email || false) }
      format.json { render :json => @user.to_json(:session => false, :authorized => user_logged_in? || publisher_logged_in? || app_logged_in?, :publisher => @publisher, :email => email || false) }
    end
  end
```

That's my code, and I'm specifically looking to understand what the following does:

```
format.json { render :json => @user.to_json(:session => false, :authorized => user_logged_in? || publisher_logged_in? || app_logged_in?, :publisher => @publisher, :email => email || false) }
```

Comment: Does your user model have an as_json method that you can post?  Most the time when you pass options like the ones above to a to_json method, you will have an as_json method in your model that will figure out what to do with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only parameters `to_json` understands are `:only`, `:except`, `:methods` and `:include` (check the docs [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)).

If your `to_json` uses other parameters it's because it (or the method `as_json`) has been overridden in your model.

Comment: I don't see `to_json` in the `User` controller or `as_json`

Comment: @Shamoon Does it change anything then if you remove the `to_json` parameters?

Comment: Kind of afraid to test. It's a live system and it's non-trivial to set up a dev environment